# We need your help moderators

Tags: discusión, soporte

Can a moderator reopen this question please?

[Download Spanish–English translations (esp. conjugations) as Open Data](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/8360/12)

This question was closed in less than 24 hours even when users (Jaime Cruz Triana, syrux) expressed the importance of the question, but the lack of support from moderators has stopped this question from being answered and discussed.

Also I request more participation from the moderators, because wrong actions have been taken and no measures have been implemented.

Comment: `wrong actions have been taken and no measures have been implemented` Which measures would you like to see implemented? The entire community is available to participate, and even re-open moderator-closed questions. Yet the question you're talking about has yet to receive even a *single* re-open vote. And so far, the only comments on the relevant meta post have been in favor of making it a community wiki question.

Comment: It would also be beneficial and help your own credibility if you had a more cooperative, and less hostile attitude. There was already a meta post made about this very issue, which *ASKED FOR YOUR OPINIONS*, and you chose instead to open a new, redundant, and hostile question.

Comment: Entonces la solución tuya es marcar mi pregunta como duplicada. Bueno,  mi objetivo en este sitio para que lo sepas es denunciar tu abuso, hacia otros. Esta acción se suma al historial de tu mal comportamiento. Solo espero que que llegue el momento justo, para con mis argumentos, revelar tu identidad.

Comment: Porque es duplicada. Si quieres ofrecer tu opinión sobre la situación, puedes hacerlo en la otra pregunta.

Comment: @syrux, no lo tomes por ese camino hermano, esto que pasa es una cosa rutinaria en casi todos los sitios de stack exchange, closed question and duplicates, no se cuanto tiempo llevas participando aqui por tu perfil puedo ver que hace dos meses, al principio es un poco chocante, pero vas aprendiendo las reglas del juego, ya como lo indican habia un tema abierto en meta con tu inquietud, ese es el lugar para llevar a cabo la discusion. como tu dices esto es manejado por la comunidad

Comment: al final se hace lo que la comunidad quiera dentro de las reglas que hay, asi que te propongo lleves tus ideas ahi y la gente ya dira que opina al respecto